# Non positive inner product

Tags: geometry

I have an inner product space $(R^3,E)$ with $E((x_1,y_1,z_1),(x_2,y_2,z_2))=x_1x_2-y_1y_2+x_2z_1+x_1z_2+z_1z_2$.The question is wether the geometry of this space is Euclidean.I tried to apply the Jacobi method but $D(3)=0$.Any ideas?

Comment: Your inner product is not positive definite

Comment: ok thanks!Is there any way to make the Jacobi's method work?